# How to put greek letters in latex knitr figure caption?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I searched for this, but wasn't able to find it. In a knitr document, I want to put $\alpha_1$ as the caption to a plot like so:

```
<<fig.cap='$\alpha_1$'>>=
 plot(1:5,1:5)
@
```

Trying to knit this comes back with the error

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.172 ...axwidth]{figure/plotSigma1} \caption[$^^G
                                              lpha_1$]{$^^Glpha_1$\label...
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nevermind - you simply need to escape the \ for alpha

```
<<fig.cap='$\\alpha_1$'>>=
 plot(1:5,1:5)
@
```

Comment: exactly, this is something that can be easily forgotten when we write \\ in a character string

Comment: Any idea how you put umlauts and other special characters in a table or figure caption, for creating pdf files with rmarkdown?